# ngShow not working with multiElement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following rendered HTML:

```
<div class="tutorial-dot ng-hide" ng-show-start="currentStep">
    <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
<div class="tutorial-modal" ng-show-end="">
```

As you can see, the ng-show-start element is hidden but the ng-show-end element is not. They should both have the same ngShow directive instance applied to them since it supports multiElement but the ngShow directive is not working properly on the ng-show-end element.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by removing the ng-hide class on the first div. I added some text just to see if the show was working.  currentStep is not initialized so it will start hiding the the divs. When you click the button it will flip the value of currentStep to true with the ng-click.

```
  <div class="tutorial-dot" ng-show-start="currentStep">
    <div class="dot">Hello, this will show when the current step is true.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tutorial-modal" ng-show-end>
    This is the end
  </div>
```

Here is a link to a codepen that demonstrates this working.  If there are more questions about this fork my codepen and show the issue you are having.  http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/PpMvzZ?#

Comment: Your code differs from mine in that the ng-show-end also has the expression as its value. Is that required? It hasn't been for other multiElement directives I've used.

Comment: I tried it with the same expression as the argument for `ng-show-end` and it still didn't work. If you change the ng-init from true to false in your example it only hides the ng-show-start, not the ng-show-end, so it doesn't work in your example either.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  remove ng-hide class from the first div.  I update the code in the answer and the codepen.